# part of sting sent from arduino to ros is missed

Tags: ros, arduino, rosserial, rosserial-python

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**part of arduino code**:

```
void loop(){
  String ang = String(angle);//angle is global value 
  String dis = String(myLidarLite.distance()); //myLidarLite.distance() is API function to get distance data
  String total = ang+'a'+ dis;

  int len = total.length();
  char toROS[len-1];
  total.toCharArray(toROS, len); 
  scan.data = toROS;  //std_msgs::String scan;
  LIDAR.publish (&scan); //ros::Publisher LIDAR("Lidar_raw", &scan);
  nh.spinOnce();   //ros::NodeHandle nh;
  delay(5);
}
```

I observed the output of this rostopic:

> ... data: 76b66
> --- data: 103b48
> --- data: 134b50
> --- data: 163b61
> --- data: 193b34
> --- data: 227b9
> --- data: 248b8
> --- data: 271b69
> --- data: 296b
> --- data: 325b54
> ...

The **dis** is missing in some data, I try to output this format string in **Serial Monitor** and it's right. It just random missed..
Any suggestions will be appreciate.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/235192/part-of-sting-sent-from-arduino-to-ros-is-missed/) by [crazymumu](https://answers.ros.org/users/21710/crazymumu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 214 on 2016-05-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

define a fixed size of char array like :**char toROS[8]** solved this problem

---

Originally posted by [crazymumu](https://answers.ros.org/users/21710/crazymumu/) with karma: 214 on 2016-05-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0